# How to update a web page from javascript without exiting javascript

Tags: javascript, refresh, reload

I would like to animate an html page with something like this:

```
function showElements(a) {   
  for (i=1; i<=a; i++)  {  
    var img = document.getElementById(getImageId(i));  
    img.style.visibility = 'visible';  
    pause(500);  
  }  
}

function pause(ms) {
  ms += new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date() < ms){}
}
```

Unfortunately, the page only renders once javascript completes.

If I add

```
 window.location.reload();
```

after each pause(500); invocation, this seems to force my javascript to exit.  (At least, I do not reach the next line of code in my javascript.)

If I insert

```
 var answer=prompt("hello");
```

after each pause(500), this does exactly what I want (i.e. update of the page) except for the fact that I don't want an annoying prompt because I don't actually need any user input.

So... is there *something* I can invoke after my pause that forces a refresh of the page, does not request any input from the user, and allows my script to continue?

Comment: Are you looking for something like the `setTimeOut` function? http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the javascript thread is running, the rendering thread will not update the page. You need to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout).

Rather than creating a second function, or exposing `i` to external code, you can implement this using an inner function with a closure on `a` and `i`:

```
function showElements(a) {
    var i = 1;
    function showNext() {
        var img = document.getElementById(getImageId(i));  
        img.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
        i++;
        if(i <= a) setTimeout(showNext, 500);
    }
    showNext();
}
```

---

> If I add `window.location.reload();` after each `pause(500)` invocation, this seems to force my javascript to exit

`window.reload()` makes the browser discard the current page and reload it from the server, hence your javascript stopping.

---

> If I insert `var answer=prompt("hello");` after each `pause(500)`, this does exactly what I want.

`prompt`, `alert`, and `confirm` are pretty much the only things that can actually pause the javascript thread. In some browsers, even these still block the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your `pause()` function sleeps on the UI thread and freezes the browser.
This is your problem.

Instead, you need to call `setTimeout` to call a function later.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is inherently event-driven/non-blocking (this is one of the great things about javascript/Node.js).  Trying to circumvent a built in feature is never a good idea.  In order to do what you want, you need to schedule your events.  One way to do this is to use setTimeout and simple recursion.

```
function showElements(a) {   
  showElement(1,a);
}

function showElement(i, max) {
   var img = document.getElementById(getImageId(i));  
   img.style.visibility = 'visible';
   if (i < max) {
      setTimeout(function() { showElement(i+1, max) }, 500);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for saying something basic that didn't come across clearly when I went through javascript tutorials: "Javascript is inherently event-driven/non-blocking". I only came to realize the implications of this now that I have to use timeout functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 1;
function showElements(a) {   
    var img = document.getElementById(getImageId(i));  
    img.style.visibility = 'visible';  
    if (i < a) {
      setTimeout(function() { showElements(a) }, 500);  
    }
    i++;
}
showElements(5);
```

Comment: This will fail if you do something like `hideAllElements()`, then later call `showElements(5)` again, since `i` will not be reset.

Comment: that condition wasn't asked in the question

Comment: Hence there being no downvote. It's just something to be aware of.

Comment: Sorry, but in your answer, calling `hideAllElements()` will hide all elements and then if it was called before `i == a` condition happens, then the previous `showElements` will still continue running

Comment: Good point. That's unavoidable without cooperating implementations of `showElements` and `hideAllElements` though - every answer here has that fault.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showElements(a,t) {   
  for (var i=1; i<=a; i++)  {  
    (function(a,b){setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById(getImageId(a)).style.visibility = 'visible'},a*b);}
    )(i,t)  
  }  
}
```

The t-argument is the delay, e.g. 500

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/nLrps/

Comment: You don't need a closure on `a*b` here

Comment: Also, this just makes the `a`th element visible `a` times in a row

Comment: Ok, you tricked me on the second point, but my first point stands.

Comment: a*b is not a closure, it's the milliseconds for setTimeout

Comment: I guess the thing that's odd to me here is that you pass `500` into the anonymous function.

Comment: Why not make the "animation" more variable?

Comment: Ok, now you're really puzzling me by passing `t` to `b` instead of _just using it_!

Comment: setTimeout will run the function in global scope, I cannot simply use t because it is unknown in global scope

Comment: But `t` is just an argument to `setTimeout`, which is invoked in the local scope

Comment: correct, I was wrong, but where do you see the problem there?